# How is the quotient space $L^2/\mathbb{R}$ defined? What is the relation to the orthogonal complement of $\mathbb{R}\subset L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

In some literature the authors state:
$$L^2/\mathbb{R}(\Omega) = \{q \in L^2(\Omega) | \int_{\Omega} q = 0\},$$
for an open and bounded domain $\Omega$.

But this seems to be a very specific definition of a quotient Hilbert space. How does one arrive to that?

Also, there seems to be a relation between $L^2/\mathbb{R}(\Omega)$ and the orthogonal complement $M^\bot$ for $M=\mathbb{R}\subset{L^2}$, where:
$$ M^\bot =  \{q \in L^2(\Omega)\, |\, (q,r)=0,\, \forall r\in \mathbb{R}\} $$
It seems like $M^\bot = L^2/\mathbb{R}(\Omega)$. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$ then $H=M\oplus M^{\perp}$ and $H|M$ is isometrically isomorphic to $M^{\perp}$ via $x+M \mapsto Qx$ where $Q$ is the orthogonal projection from $H$ onto $M^{\perp}$.

Comment: So we can write $H/M = M^\perp$? And then if $\exists c \in M$ s.t. $x+c \in M^\perp$ we have that $x \in M^\perp$?

Comment: Quite often Functional Analysts write equality of spaces to signify that they are isometrically isomorphic. They are not equal as sets. @Someone

Comment: Thanks @geetha290krm! How about the second question in my first comment?

Comment: Yes, if $x+c$ is orthogonal to $M$ so is $x$.

Comment: Thanks, that's great help!